# How do I supposed to use Knockout Validation and Knockcout X-editable at the same time?

Tags: knockout.js, twitter-bootstrap-3, knockout-validation, x-editable

I'm using Bootstrap, Knockout and X-editable with knockout bindings in my ASP.NET project.
I cannot get the validation to work. According to knockout x-editable (https://github.com/brianchance/knockout-x-editable):

> "If you are using knockout.validation, I have wired up a call to the observable's isValid for editable.validate. To work, this has to push the new value into the observable, then validate, then revert back. If you have subscribed to changes, you will see them. Not the best choice, but works."

That's true, the isValid is called. I'm setting up the knockout variable like this (Knockout validation):

```
self.num1 = ko.observable().extend({ number: true, min: 0.01, max: 10e10 });
```

In my cshtml I include `bootstrap-editable.css`, and `bootstrap-editable.js`, `knockout-{version}.js`, `knockout.validation.js`, `knockout.x-editable.js`. I have no error message on the console, the x-editable dialog pops up nicely and the value change takes place. However the validation just doesn't happen. I thought x-editable will relay the validation to what I defined with knockout validation by itself. SHould I implement any isValid function or something? How would I trigger Knockout.Validation if I implement an isValid? I'm lost.

Comment: Have you configured knockout validation using ko.validation.configure?

Comment: Should I? Let me check on that.

Comment: Yes. You need to do that

Comment: You can call init instead, did you call that?

Comment: I thought that there's a default configuration. I'm checking.

Comment: I think you still need to call init. Try adding ko.validation.init();

Comment: In my jsfiddle I need to call init. If I comment it out it doesn't display error messages: http://jsfiddle.net/85pt31rL/

Comment: I tried to add it before and then after the applyBindings. Probably I have the error elsewhere. Maybe I rule out x-editable and look if the validation works without it.

Comment: Ok, I got the problem. My configuration was actually like this: `self.num1 = ko.observable().extend({ number: true, min: 0.01, max: 10e10, numeric: 2 });`. The last thing "numeric" is my own validation binding and it interferes with the ko validation in a way that no validation happens (no error message either). So I need to refine my own extension. It'd check if the number has two decimal fractional digit.

Comment: In my setup ko.validation works out of the box even without explicitly calling init. I shouldn't have introduced my special validation binding and the knockout x-editable at the same time... past 2am here, time to sleep :P

Comment: Is you special validation using knockout validation. Take a look at https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/User-Contributed-Rules

Comment: I'm on it, still not sleeping :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My configuration was actually like this: `self.num1 = ko.observable().extend({ number: true, min: 0.01, max: 10e10, numeric: 2 });`. The last thing `"numeric"` is my own validation binding and it interferes with the ko validation in a way that no validation happens (no error message either).

If you want to use own validation, follow this: https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/User-Contributed-Rules

Another thing to consider about knockout x-editable validation binding:

> To work, this has to push the new value into the observable, then validate, then revert back. If you have subscribed to changes, you will see them.

So you'll see more changes, which are induced by the binding itself, and not just your value change. You need to filter those out somehow, if you subscribe to a bound variable.

Answer (score 0):

Validation only works with the value and selectedOptions out of the box, if you use a custom binding you need to use `ko.validation.makeBindingHandlerValidatable`

```
ko.validation.makeBindingHandlerValidatable("selectedOptions");
```